# Adding kendo grid toolbar at the top and bottom

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that has many records. Everytime the user edit a record in the bottom of the grid he needs to scroll just to save the record he edit. Is it possible to add the toolbar at the bottom and top of kendo grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [kendoWidgetCreated event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#global-angular-events-emitted-by-the-kendo-bindings) to adjust the toolbar on bottom. Like [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/@popov/AyUpa)

Comment: it will only add a toolbar at the bottom of the grid but not on the top.

Comment: Replace "insertAfter" with "insertBefore" in the code given above... to add toolbar on the top of the content section of the grid....If you want to add toolbar on the top of the grid header thn try this:  $scope.myGrid.element.find(".k-grid-toolbar").insertBefore($scope.myGrid.element.find(".k-grid-header"));